# Play remote videos with local media player

Tags: remote, video-player

I have some videos on a remote machine and have to copy them to the local when want to enjoy them with a local media player such as VLC or mpv.

Is it possible to play them over ssh or alternatives without moving them to the local?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using vlc's built-in network stream functionality along with an open directory of video on your remote server. All you'd have to do is expose a directory of video with software like apache, nginx, etc. which allow you to expose directories of images/html/video/audio for remote downloading. Seeing as you use ask ubuntu, you probably wouldn't use Microsoft Media Server(mms), but various open alternatives like rstp(commonly used by ipcams), or my personal favorite, [RTMP](https://medium.com/@yenthanh/setup-a-rtmp-livestream-server-in-15-minutes-with-srs-1b0046c77267)

[image: vlc screenshot]